# Email client support negative margin value?

Tags: html, css, position, margin, email-client

Please have look the below screenshot

[image]

I want to positioned the lens in top area.Sadly the `position` value is not supported by email clients.so what can i do for that.can i use for `margin-top` value as minus value? hope you can help me..thanks in advance

Comment: I think your best bet is to have a table structure like this : http://i.imgur.com/1ZhL4ae.png

Comment: @NickR you mean cut to different part to that image..

Comment: Yep - rather than mess around with negative margins etc.

Comment: sorry it is not possible for me..you have any other idea?

Comment: Not really, as this is the most robust way of doing it.

Comment: Email client HTML/CSS is very basic, especially in Microsoft Outlook. Nick R's example of using tables and images is the only method likely to be compatible with all the most popular clients.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hotmail and Outlook.com no longer support the following CSS properties:

```
margin
margin-top
margin-right
margin-bottom
margin-left
```

Here is the statement given by [Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/hotmail-and-outlook-com-drop-support-for-margin) ..

Comment: @ you are wrong..plz check the link http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/.. Gmail is working fine.

Comment: @Nikhilkrishnan can you pass the rough HTML page so i can test it and give a try.

Comment: Gmail and Hotmail do support margins: as @Krish stated: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ Where did you get your source that they don't work in those browsers?

Comment: @aaron-coding I've updated the answer and added the source code as well.. I hope you will not say that Litmus is lying..

Comment: @KheemaPandey Ok, I un-down-voted your answer because of your added source.

Comment: @Krish
your link is obsolete, Gmail does not support minus margin see this link https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps#gmail_tip4

Comment: Link is not valid, so I downvoted the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Although the question was asked a while ago I decided to give an update since there was not complete answer and the question might still occur.

Edit:

I couldn't resist but test position relative and margin-top with a negative value it in a few mail clients...

- Thunderbird 60: Supports both ✓
- Gmail.com (in Firefox): Supports neither
- Outlook.live.com (in Firefox): Supports neither
- Roundcube 1.2.0 (in Firefox): Supports both ✓
- K9 5.600 (in Android): Supports both (but positioning is very though) ✓

I have not tested most e-mail clients since this is enough data for me not to use it at the moment (2020-03).

Original:

The position property would support a solution as stated in the question. Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

I haven't tested it but according to https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/ Outlook, Apple mail, Windows Live mail, iOS 6, Android 4.2, Android 2.3 support properties position and top.

Gmail, Yahoo!, Gmail app, Outlook 2007 - 2013 and DO NOT support the position property.

Only Outlook.com in the list can not use margin. I'm sorry that I can't confirm if negative margins can be used.

Comment: I can confirm that Apple mail supports it and Gmail on Chromium based browser does not